# Java: getInstance() Singleton performance

Tags: java, performance

I'm having trouble of finding the correct approach of using singleton classes the most performance friendly way. I have 3 approaches, maybe someone can explain me the most efficient way:

1:

```
public functionA() {
    SingletonClassA.getInstance().callA();
    SingletonClassA.getInstance().callB();
    SingletonClassA.getInstance().callC();
    SingletonClassA.getInstance().callD();
    SingletonClassA.getInstance().callE();
}
```

2.

```
public functionA() {
    SingletonClassA tmp = SingletonClassA.getInstance();
    tmp.callA();
    tmp.callB();
    tmp.callC();
    tmp.callD();
    tmp.callE();
}
```

3.

```
SingletonClassA tmp = SingletonClassA.getInstance();       
public functionA() {
    tmp.callA();
    tmp.callB();
    tmp.callC();
    tmp.callD();
    tmp.callE();
}
```

I see code in which approach 1 is used, but I think the better way would be 2 (or 3 if other function are also using `SingletonClassA`).

I'm coming from c-development but I don't know much about Java and it's references. I just want it to not consume much memory and be fast on execution.

Comment: Have you measured each approach for your use case? To be honest, this sort of micro-optimisation is unlikely to have an observable effect.

Comment: I understand why someone with a C background would ask a question like this but you do not need to concern yourself with a micro-optimization like this. You are using Java now, the code will be slow either way ... :)

Answer (score 3):

Never think (or correctly phrased: assume/believe) when talking about performance.

Instead: read about the Java just-in-time compiler and what it does. And surprise: most of the time the JIT will turn such micro-optimization ideas like yours ... down the tube. Only go for performance issues if you really experience issues. And then: learn to use a java profiler to measure what is going on.

Meaning: focus on [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) design; write readable, maintainable code ... that typically results in "good" code anyway; and is much more rewarding than spending time on such things in Java. Besides: if your code is maintainable, it will be much easier to make changes in order to fix certain performance problems.

(yes, one should avoid making stupid mistakes; but the first and biggest mistake is to **assume** that doing this versus that has a good/bad effect on performance).

Side note: consider not using singleton classes, but enums clases with a single instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use an enum with a single instance.

If you care about a singleton in a concurrent environment and you want lazy initialization, go for the [Initialization-on-demand pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the most performant version, the 3rd approach is pretty close, however you should use a private final static variable, to avoid unnecessary additional look-ups:

```
private static final SingletonClassA singletonA = SingletonClassA.getInstance();       
public functionA() {
    singletonA.callA();
    singletonA.callB();
    singletonA.callC();
    singletonA.callD();
    singletonA.callE();
}
```

I assume that the way your Singleton is created, it won't change later on, so `static` is also a good choice. Static will save 4/8 byte of memory (32/64 bit VM) per instance of the class, as the variable will no longer be part of potentially many instances of the class, it will only exist exactly once.

`final` hints to the compiler that this variable won't change after the initial declaration, so there is no need for any checks for changes. Note that this is only a hint that will make the decision for the compiler easier. In most cases the compiler can determine this on its own. It is however also good practice to hint a read-only variable to the reader of your code, and `final` does exactly that.

`private` makes sure that the variable is not part of inheritable class section, so checks for class hierarchies can be skipped. This is however more a compile-time performance gain, as the JVM can always exactly determine which version from the class hierarchy has to be used.

Also note that class variables should always have a clear name indicating their purpose. `tmp` is neither clear nor does it describe the purpose.

**However:** The performance gain in the unoptimized code will be a few nanoseconds at best, and should that function be part of the so called 'hot' functions (= it is called frequently), it will be optimized far beyond what you can do with standard Java code anyways. So the performance gain by rewriting the code in this specific case is entirely negligible.

Unless you have a specific reason to believe that your code is hindering performance, it is always better to write code that is easy to read and to maintain, than to optimize at such a minor level. The JVM is much better at doing that for you, because it knows a lot more details about the executing machine. Optimizations you do on an Intel machine might i.E. cause the code to execute slower on an ARM system.

Optimizations should always start on the architectural (global) level, and only if you have measured and proven that certain code parts are still too slow afterwards, you should start thinking about such micro-level optimizations.